# getting so many errors while doing "npm install"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, msbuild, node-gyp

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web Application with Angular (I have VS2019 Enterprise installed on Windows 10), it is working fine and everything but when I try to publish it to Azure App Service. I get many errors on the `npm i` step.

I tried all the solutions I could find:

- install **windows-build-tools**
- update visual studio and install **Desktop Build Tools**
- install **node-gyp**
- modify **configure.js** of node-gyp in node_modules
- Uninstall Node and reinstall the latest version

I still cannot make it work.

the latest error I got is this :

```
npm install

> node-sass@4.9.3 install C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 C:\Python27\python2.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python2.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 12.14.1
gyp verb command install [ '12.14.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "12.14.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 12.14.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 12.14.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python2.EXE
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\.node-gyp\\12.14.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\.node-gyp\\12.14.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\.node-gyp\\12.14.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\bibaghdad\.node-gyp\12.14.1
gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
EXEC(0,0): Error : spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bibaghdad\\Documents\\Projects\\commercial-innovation-portal\\InnovationsPortal\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bibaghdad\Documents\Projects\commercial-innovation-portal\InnovationsPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
EXEC(0,0): Error code: 7
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Did you try to reintall nodejs or update it to the latest?

Comment: yes, I tried that too.

Comment: what about setting your proxy?

Comment: what proxy? I do not have any proxy here.

Comment: Looks like `node-sass@4.9.3` isn't compatible with `node.js 12.14.1`. You either have to upgrade node-sass to 4.12.0 or downgrade node.js to 10.x

Comment: this error is not affecting the build process it is ignoring it and crashing somewhere else on the `MSBuild.exe`

Answer (score 4):

You can try to remove package-lock.json and relaunch `npm install`

It worked for me, thanks to this comment https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2773#issuecomment-559399501

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is an issue with `node-gyp`. From your error log I can see the version is old  `[3.x]` which shouldn't be and you should update the version to latest.

If you are using `MacOS`, you can update `node-gyp` to latest version using this command:

```
$ [sudo] npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp@latest
```

The `sudo` above is optional. Use it only if necessary.

If you are on `Windows`, you can update the `node-gyp` version to latest following the document [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp)

If this resolves your problem and you are curious about `node-gyp` you can always read it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp)

Comment: In that case, could you please let me know your node and npm version ?